# Html is being truncated on save in drupal (full html)

Tags: drupal, xhtml

If I unput a certain piece html into my page, it seems to be truncating:

```
<div id="slideshow">    
    <img style="cursor: pointer;" src="files:img/slideshow/3.png" id="left_slide" alt=""/>    
    <img style="cursor: pointer;" src="files:img/slideshow/1.png" id="center_slide" alt=""/>    
    <img style="cursor: pointer;" src="files:img/slideshow/2.png" id="right_slide" alt=""/>    
   </div>
```

It all looks good in the preview, but when I save it it becomes:

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <img style="cursor: pointer;" src="http://local.drupal.com/sites/default/files/img/slideshow/3.png" id="left_slide" alt="" />
</div>
```

I'm at a loss! I'm not using any nasty WYSIWYG editors and the input format is full html. The second code example indicates that I'm using the path filter module but I've also tried disabling that and resaving. It still truncates.

I'm using Drupal 6.19.

Comment: It sounds like a bug, or misconfiguration in an input-format (aka filters). Do you have any thirdparty filters/input formats enabled?

Comment: No, after more detective work, it seems like its being rendered in 'teaser' mode. My template just spits out $content, so I'm not sure where to set it to render in FULL view.

Comment: Where is this HTML being placed? In the body field, or in a CCK field? Do you see this on the actual node page (e.g. when you go to node/42) or only when it's part of a view or a list of nodes?

Comment: It's just being truncated by teaser settings. Don't worry, everyone gets caught by this at least once in their drupal lifespan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly print the teaser only.

To publish to the front page the complete node Go to Administer > Content Management > Post Settings > Choose 'unlimited' from the 'length of trimmed post' select box.

You can also manually controlling the teaser break point by inserting:

```
  <!--break-->
```

If you use a views you can control if you want to show the complete node or the teaser in the settings of the view.